# Call a function or method from inside its class

Tags: php, class

I have written a database class but can't access the method from within:

```
class database{
.
.
private $mgc;
private $real;
public function insert($table,$values,$row = null){
.
.
 for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++){
    $values[$i] = safe_value ($values[$i]);      
    } 
.
.
}
public function safe_value( $value ) {
    if( $this->real ) {  
        if( $this->mgc ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
    } 
    else {  

        if( !$this->mgc ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }

    }
    return $value;
} 

}
```

When running this class I have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function safe_value()

When I used `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of the `safe_value` method the class works perfectly. Why can't I access the `safe_value` function and why is it showing me this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling a non-static member function from within the class you need to refer to it using `$this`, in this particular case you should call it as

```
$values[$i] = $this->safe_value($values[$i]);
```

Comment: But why `$values[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string ($values[$i]);` has not this error?

Comment: @phpExe, because `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't a member function of your class, it's just a library function available to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the call to `$values[$i] = $this->safe_value($values[$i]);` for non-static methods.  For static methods, use `$values[$i] = database::safe_value($values[$i])`.